# How to implent week view calender in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to implement a Week View Calender like the ones below. Another example may be the ICS Google Calender. The events will come from a database. So far i don't know where to start. Any ideas how i do this? Code and layout will be appreciated.

---

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ypu got any solution for this.. if yes please share

Comment: You could take a look at this https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View

Answer (score 2):

The calendar application that comes with stock android is open source. You can see the [source code here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar). Getting a feel for this applications layout might be a good place to start.

Maybe you'll want to reuse some of this code.

Answer (score 2):

Android Week View. can you use this [Source code here](https://github.com/AnilMH/Android-WeekView-Demo)